# git sparseCheckout repo pushes full repo to remote

Tags: git

I found a git repo that has something I need, but only part of it. So I pulled its content with `sparseCheckout=true` and set the `sparse-checkout` file.

After pull, the local repo looks good. But when I try to push this repo to another remote git repo, it seems it ignores the *sparseCheckout* config and pushes the full repo to my new remote.

How can I make git only pushes whatever at my local to my new remote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. Sparse checkout is sparse *checkout* – it only changes which files are extracted into the working-directory, but does not modify the actual commit history and does not change what is transferred. Each commit still contains a complete snapshot of the entire repository, and Git won't let you download parts of a commit, nor will it let you push parts of a commit either. (Yes, this also means your `git pull` has downloaded the whole thing, too.)

*(This is different from shallow clones, where Git actually avoids transferring older commits than requested.)*